# $2x^2-4x+xy^2-1$ Find extrema of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this function 
$$f(x,y)=2x^2-4x+xy^2-1$$
 and I need to find extrema of this function. What I found is:

The critical points are: $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$

And according to formula $$ D = f''_{xx}(x_0,y_0)\cdot f''_{yy}(x_0,y_0)-f''_{xy}(x_0,y_0) $$
at $(0,2)$ $ D=-4<0 $ hence $(0,2)$ is a saddle point

at $(0,-2)$ $ D=4>0 $ and $ f''_{xx}(0,-2)=4 $ hence it's a minimum

at $(1,0)$ $ D=8>0 $ and $ f''_{xx}(1,0)=4 $ hence it's a minimum

Now my problem is my book and [This Gadget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=597dd91e6b177f393877f173f231593f) are proving me wrong

books says the only minima is $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ are both saddle points whereas the mentioned gadget tells there is no saddle point

I: $(0,2)$ is a saddle point and $(1,0)$ and $(0,-2)$ are both minima of this function

Book: $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ are both saddle points and only $(1,0)$ is minimum

mentioned gadget: there is no saddle point at all

Comment: You forgot a square in D in $...-f_{xy}''(x_0,y_0)$

Comment: Wish I could express here, how stupid I am. Thanks Stef I've been messing with this since last night. I wasn't squaring the last term in D, Thanks again. Now I will figure out if Book is wrong or Gadget.

Comment: Haha, no problem, good luck with it!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The correct formula is $$ D = f''_{xx}(x_0,y_0)\cdot f''_{yy}(x_0,y_0)-f''_{xy}(x_0,y_0)^{\color{blue}2} $$